# how to update cart codeigniter using JQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

How to get all the input with JQuery?
Thank all for help!

`$i.'[rowid]'` and `$i.'[qty]'`

```
<?php echo form_open('path/to/controller/update/function'); ?>

<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%" border="0">

<tr>
  <th>QTY</th>
  <th>Item Description</th>
  <th style="text-align:right">Item Price</th>
  <th style="text-align:right">Sub-Total</th>
</tr>

<?php $i = 1; ?>

<?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>

    <?php echo form_hidden($i.'[rowid]', $items['rowid']); ?>

    <tr>
      <td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => $i.'[qty]', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5')); ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $items['name']; ?>

            <?php if ($this->cart->has_options($items['rowid']) == TRUE): ?>

                <p>
                    <?php foreach ($this->cart->product_options($items['rowid']) as $option_name => $option_value): ?>

                        <strong><?php echo $option_name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $option_value; ?><br />

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

      </td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']); ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['subtotal']); ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php $i++; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2"> </td>
  <td class="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
  <td class="right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total()); ?></td>
</tr>

</table>

<p><?php echo form_submit('', 'Update your Cart'); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
echo form_hidden('rowid['.$i.']', $items['rowid']);
```

and:

```
echo form_input(array('name' => 'qty['.$i.']', //etc
```

... but you could just as well get rid of the `$i` variable and go:

```
echo form_hidden('rowid[]', $items['rowid']);
```

the only difference being that the `rowid`inputs will start at index 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I want to keep the code and get all the input with jquery, can you help